# Expose local server python?

Tags: python

I have a two socket scripts which I want to access from outside local network but None of these solution seem to work.Tried this [Accessing python server (web server) using ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741910/accessing-python-server-web-server-using-ngrok) and this https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#python-tcp-server-and-client and this https://gist.github.com/Jc2k/61aeb5b551d006b17f97 didn't work for me.
Windows 7 python 3.8.8
Any other solution?

Comment: I think this question is too open-ended for stackoverflow. You may have better luck on sister sites. Its more of a network administration question.

Comment: Can you tell which site?

Comment: serverfault.com may be the best, it does more with network infrastructure. But superuser.com is another good options. They are both run by stackexchange, like this site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solution may work it worked for me

https://youtu.be/HI1kbr6vBhQ

Just follow the screen as the voice is in another language.

1. First setup ngrok
2. Then `ngrok tcp port-no`
3. It will return 'forwarding' which will have a port number put it in your file
4. Then ping the thing it returned it will return the ip then put it in client file

That's all

Comment: A link to a YouTube tutorial isn't a very good answer. The link can get removed at any point in time so the answer would be no longer valid for anyone.

Comment: That worked for me and there was no other article pointed towards it. Also why downvote please remove it

Comment: The answer works for me thanks @DevilIshere

Comment: Please summarize the content of the video. As AKX said, answers that don't have any substance beyond a link are not acceptable here. You can keep the link, but describe within your answer what the solution is.

Comment: I edited the answer now remove the downvote